# Tkinter Label won't appear inside Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame

I have two frames: `big_frame` and `small_frame`. `small_frame` is inside of `big_frame`, and I want to place a label inside of `small_frame`.

The label won't appear inside the frame and the problem is on line 8: removing the sticky allows the label to appear inside the frame. Am I doing something wrong, is there a work-around that still allows the frame to resize as the window is resized?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')

# Big Frame
big_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Big Frame', width=350, height=450, padx=5, pady=5)
big_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(1, 0), sticky='nsew')  # the sticky prevents the label from being inside the frame

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Small Frame
small_frame = LabelFrame(big_frame, text='Small Frame', width=120, height=200).grid(row=0, column=0)

label = Label(small_frame, text='Label')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)


mainloop()
```

Comment: `grid` returns `None` - you must first assign `small_frame`, then call `small_frame.grid(...)` as the next instruction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a small fix gridding smallframe after initializing

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')

# Big Frame
big_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Big Frame', width=350, height=450, padx=5, pady=5)
big_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(1, 0), sticky='nsew')  # the sticky prevents the label from being inside the frame

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Small Frame
small_frame = LabelFrame(big_frame, text='Small Frame', width=120, height=200)
small_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

label = Label(small_frame, text='Label')
label.grid(row=0, sticky='nw')


mainloop()
```